# How can I detect what section of a wall I have clicked on?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am just asking if my logic behind this makes sense, and if there is maybe a better way to go about it.

Lets say I have a wall prefab, I want to divide that into 9 different subsections. Here is what my plan is (pseudocode):

```
//Lets pretend I connected these values to the transform of my wall. by 
the way I coded this off the top of the head so expect syntax errors. 

Private Int wallHeight;
Private Int wallLength;

Private Int cubeLength;
Private Int cubeHeight;
Private Int spaceBetween; 

private vector3[] cubeLocations; 

void start()
{
spaceBetween = 1; 

cubeLength = wallWidth / 3; 
cubeHeight = wallWidth / 3;

/* Im thinking of doing a for loop that lists all of the points into a vector list.

The trouble i am having is figuring out the logic behind this for loop. I need to place one, then add the space in between, then place another. 
I know it goes something around this but I am missing a key point. 
*/ 

for I in range of (9):
 if (I == 0 )
   {     
    cubeLocations.append(0, 0, 0
   }
 else
   {   
    + spaceBetween;
    cubeLocations.append(cubeLength, cubeHeight, 0);

}
```

In the end I need those points into a vector 3 so that I could say if the mouse position is in between these two points of a cube and clicks. It selects that cube.

Is a loop the right approach?

Comment: I could technically go the route of placing empty game objects in the desired spots and instantiate those points on top. However I wanted to try it this way and put some math behind it.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with creating an array for every wall.  When a wall is clicked, find the `Vector3 worldLocation` of where the click's ray hits the wall, then do a `Vector3 localLocation = wallTransform.InverseTransformPoint(worldLocation);` and use that to determine where on the wall you clicked, and you can figure out which section of the wall was clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for changing that for me, didn't realize. I understand your point. I will test that out! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Also not sure how to mark this as you answered it. Thank you though overall.

Comment: Whomever provided a solution your question needs to create an answer (yourself included), then you can mark that answer as the solution.

Comment: @Laskio I wrote up some code to go with my comment. You can accept that as the answer if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of generating an array of points for every wall, just use `InverseTransformPoint` when there is a click, and compare it to the height/width of the wall:

```
// In MonoBehaviour attached to wall (which also has collider attached)

void OnMouseDown() 
{
    Ray mouseRay = ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition); 
    float rayDistance = 200f;

    RaycastHit hit;
    // May need to include a `layerMask` parameter to make this work
    if (Physics.Raycast(mouseRay, out hit, rayDistance) )
    {
        Vector3 localHitPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);

        // If the wall collider is centered at local origin,
        // boundaries between outer thirds and middle are at
        // ± 1/6 of wall size.
        if (localHitPosition.x < -wallWidth/6f)
        {
            if (localHitPosition.y < -wallHeight/6f) 
                ClickedLowerLeft();
            else if (localHitPosition.y > wallHeight/6f)
                ClickedUpperLeft();
            else 
                ClickedMiddleLeft();
        }
        else if (localHitPosition.x > wallWidth/6f)
        {
            if (localHitPosition.y < -wallHeight/6f) 
                ClickedLowerRight();
            else if (localHitPosition.y > wallHeight/6f)
                ClickedUpperRight();
            else 
                ClickedMiddleRight();
        }
        else 
        {
            if (localHitPosition.y < -wallHeight/6f) 
                ClickedLowerMiddle();
            else if (localHitPosition.y > wallHeight/6f)
                ClickedUpperMiddle();
            else 
                ClickedCenter();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you a million up votes. Thank you for your help. This will not only solve this question but also many different scenarios.